# What kind of a strange interface implementation is that?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, webspeech-api

This little code snippet is from [an example](https://github.com/m-hassan-tariq/WebSpeechAPIAngular2) demonstrating the usage of the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API) in Angular and it's giving me a hard time understanding it.

I've been googling a lot how TypeScript defines and handles interfaces but couldn't find a similarly styled syntax with an explanation.

```
interface IWindow extends Window {
  webkitSpeechRecognition: any;
  SpeechRecognition: any;
}
...
const { webkitSpeechRecognition }: IWindow = <IWindow>window;   // ??
const speechRecognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();        // ??
...
```

It's the last two rows I can't interpret. I see the result of course that speechRecognition somehow becomes a [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) interface, but I don't get it how it happened and I'd like to know whether this is a fine implementation or there are prettier ways doing that.

---

And I'd also like to know that, how this solves the issue of vendor-prefixed properties for *SpeechRecognition vs webkitSpeechRecognition* because e.g. [Mozilla recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) to define SpeechRecognition a little differently:

```
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what you're confused about is actually JavaScript, not TypeScript. The feature is called [**destructing assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

If you have the following object...

```
const obj = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
```

...you can grab its propertes like this...

```
const foo = obj.foo
const bar = obj.bar
const baz = obj.baz
```

...or, the equivalent of above, with destructing assignment:

```
const {foo, bar, baz} = obj
```

So, in your case,

```
const { webkitSpeechRecognition }: IWindow = <IWindow>window;
```

is equivalent to

```
const webkitSpeechRecognition = (<IWindow>window).webkitSpeechRecognition
```

In the next line, a usual constructor call is used with `new` to create a new instance of the class.

---

And you're right, it does handle the vendor prefixes, at least not in the snippet you provided here.